# Problem of Global symbol "$new_cat_id" requires explicit package name at merging3.pl

Tags: package, explicit, requires

I want to run the merging3.pl. but alway have errors like this:

Global symbol "$new_cat_id" requires explicit package name at merging3.pl line 2
51.
Global symbol "$new_cat_id" requires explicit package name at merging3.pl line 2
65.
Execution of merging3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

This is that parts of my merging3.pl

# Get facets/categories
   my $query_local1 = "SELECT id, category_name FROM category ";
   my $query_local2 = "WHERE id=$new_cat_id AND deleted=0";
   my $query_local = $query_local1.$query_local2;
   my $query_handle_local = $connect->prepare($query_local);
      $query_handle_local->execute();

my ($lid, $lname);
   $query_handle_local->bind_columns(\$lid, \$lname);
   while ($query_handle_local->fetch()) {

```
  # print "local name= "."$lname\n";
  #if name composite with a slash, take only first word
  $lname =~ s/\/[^\/]*//;

  # Get global facets/categories
  my $query_global = "SELECT id, category_name FROM category WHERE id=our $new_cat_id AND deleted=0";
  my $query_handle_global = $connect->prepare($query_global);
  $query_handle_global->execute();
```

Thank you and Really appreciate it!